# Vue.js template with data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been working with Vue.js for a few days, and I’m trying to add a new div with the text in an input each time I press the enter button. Can you please help me to review this code?

**Script**

```
window.onload = function () {
        Vue.component('todo-item', {
            props: ['todo'],
            template: '<div id="div{{todo.id}}">{{ todo.text }}</div>'
        });

        var app7 = new Vue({
            el: '#app-7',
            data() {
                return {
                    divList: [],
                    textInput:''
                }
            },
            methods: {
                addUser() {                        
                    return this.divList.push({
                        id: + new Date,
                        text: textInput
                    });
                }
            }
        });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app-7">
              <input v-model="textInput" v-on:keyup.enter="addUser" />
              <todo-item v-for="item in divList" v-bind:todo="item" v-bind:key="item.id"></todo-item>
          </div>
```

On the JavaScript console, if I check the value of **app7.textInput**, I see it is not binding properly...

Comment: You're just missing `this` in front of `textInput` in your `addUser` method. It should be `text: this.textInput`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Bert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38065/bert) i just had to do that change and delete cache

```
         methods: {
                        addUser() {
                            return this.divList.push({
                                id: + new Date,
                                text: this.textInput
                            });
                        }
                    }
```